# Maven cannot find JDK on Ubuntu arm64

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Tensorflow for Nvidia Jetson TK1 following this instruction:
http://cudamusing.blogspot.com/2015/11/building-tensorflow-for-jetson-tk1.html

however, when I get to the part I need to call maven, I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/mvn: 167: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java: not found
```

but if I do

```
ls  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
```

It is there.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOB7G.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an 32-bit JDK on a 64-bit OS? In that case I saw similar behavior. What is the output of 'file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'?

The expected output on a 64-bit system should look similar to:

ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, BuildID[sha1]=a558f547fe0b95fdc6a109cb7d9692d6d7969794, not stripped

If the actual output is in the line of:

ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped

you are using a 32-bit java. The file not found results from the non presence of a 32-bit libc.

You can install either 32-bit support libraries or a 64-bit java implementation, which is, in my opinion, the better solution.